# Displaying/hiding JSON info based on clicked item in React/MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating an FAQ section based on a JSON file I have that has an array of objects with 'Question' and 'Answer. [image]
It's set up to where when you click on the question on the left, it displays the corresponding answer to the right...which does work correctly. The problem is I want to hide the data when the user clicks on that question again and that part is not working. When I click on a question again it will change the icon but doesn't change the box on the right. I want the Answer box to completely disappear when the question is clicked on again.

I'm guessing it's something that I'm doing wrong with setting the state:

```html
const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState({});
  const [displayAnswer, setDisplayAnswer] = useState();

  const handleClick = (index) => () => {
    setClickedIndex((state) => ({
      [index]: !state[index],
    }));
    setDisplayAnswer(faqdata[index].Answer);
    console.log(displayAnswer);
  };
```

```html
<Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item>
              <List
                style={{
                  maxHeight: 430,
                  width: 500,
                  overflow: 'auto',
                  border: '1px solid black',
                }}
              >
                {faqdata.map((item, index) => (
                  <ListItem style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                      {clickedIndex[index] ? <RemoveIcon /> : <AddIcon />}
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText
                      primary={item.Question}
                      onClick={handleClick(index)}
                    />
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
              </List>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <List
                style={{
                  maxHeight: 430,
                  width: 500,
                  overflow: 'auto',
                  border: '1px solid black',
                }}
              >
                <ListItem>{displayAnswer}</ListItem>
              </List>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a single state variable to store the currently open answer which can be:

- null (meaning that no answer is open)
- a number (meaning the answer to the question with that index is open)

```
const Container = () => {
  const [openQuestion, setOpenQuestion] = useState(null);

  const toggleOpenQuestion = (index) => {
    if(openQuestion === index) {
      setOpenQuestion(null)
    } 

    setOpenQuestion(index)
  }

  return <UIComponents openQuestion={openQuestion} toggleOpenQuestion={toggleOpenQuestion}/>
}
```

Then in the UI you can work out what to display based on this value as follows:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item>
    <List
      style={{
        maxHeight: 430,
        width: 500,
        overflow: "auto",
        border: "1px solid black",
      }}
    >
      {faqdata.map((item, index) => (
        <ListItem style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            {openQuestion === index ? <RemoveIcon /> : <AddIcon />}
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={item.Question} onClick={() => toggleOpenQuestion(index)} />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <List
      style={{
        maxHeight: 430,
        width: 500,
        overflow: "auto",
        border: "1px solid black",
      }}
    >
      <ListItem>{displayAnswer}</ListItem>
    </List>
  </Grid>
</Grid>;
```

Worth mentioning here that you should probably wrap the toggleOpenQuestion function in a useCallback to prevent uneccessary re-renders in the child component:

```
const toggleOpenQuestion = useCallback((index) => {
    if(openQuestion === index) {
      setOpenQuestion(null)
    } 

    setOpenQuestion(index)
}, [openQuestion])
```